# CSS object fit image expands layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I have some child divs placed in a parent div. It looks like that:
[image]

Now I need to place an image with a relative size into the red(brown) div. 
But every time when I place the image into the div the layouts expands. 
And that is a problem for me.

So how can I put an image with a relative size into my div without expanding the div layout?

HTML:

```
 <div class="textContentContainer">

                <div class="FirstSectionContentHeader">
                   <table class="layoutTable"><tr><td class="centerDiv">
                        <div class="FirstSectionHeaderintroText uppercase">
                            SOME TEXT
                        </div>
                    </td></tr></table>
                </div>

                <div class="FirstSectionLogoArea">
                <img src="../img/Headerlogo.png" alt="Description" class="FirstSectionTitleLogo">
                </div>

                <div class="FirstSectionIntroText usualText">
                  ddd
                </div>

                <div class="FirstSectionBottomLayout">
                    <img src="../img/basics/Pfeil.png" alt="Pfeil" class="FirstSectionBottomArrow">
                </div>


            </div>
```

CSS

```
.FirstSectionContentHeader{
    height:10%;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight:200;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.FirstSectionLogoArea{
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: chartreuse;
}

.FirstSectionTitleLogo{
    height:80%;
    width:100%;
    object-fit:contain;
}

.FirstSectionIntroText {
    height:70%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:white;
}

.FirstSectionBottomLayout{
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: brown;
}

.FirstSectionBottomArrow {
    height:10%;
    width:10%;
    object-fit:scale-down;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the image has `position: static`by default, which is "inserted" in the parent element and "takes some space" there, causing the parent element to become larger. You can give it `position: absolute`(which requires that the parent element has `position: relative`) and still use percentage values.